# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found. The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet

Написал простейший сервлет.

```
@WebServlet("/s")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("Hello Word");
    }
}
```

И web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]"

через мавен создаётся ".war". правда в плагинах есть ошибки, не нашёл как починить, но не думаю что проблема в этом.
[image: maven]

Но по итогу выдаёт вот что:
[image: 404]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обращаться к сервлету надо по такому адресу:

```
locaolhost:8080/имя варника/url сервлета
```

Если вы используете tomcat:

самый простой способ обратиться по контексту (имя варника) через страницу

```
localhost:8080/manager
```

перед этим в файле tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml можно добавить строчку

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat, manager-gui, admin-gui"/>
```

И при входе на страницу localhost:8080/manager использовать логин\пароль: tomcat

---

Естественно если вы установили другой порт, то обращаться надо по нему а не по 8080

Так же файл web.xml должен находиться по адресу WEB-IBF/web.xml в корне проекта

Comment: Если деплоить через localhost:8080/manager, выдаёт:

Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Сайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение.

Comment: не обязательно деплоить через менеджера, но через него вы можете увидеть все задепоинные проекты, если не помните название своего. Так же переместите web.xml по адресу WEB-IBF/web.xml в корне проекта

Answer (score 0):

Надо в web.xml исправить здесь (вообще названия переменных, url, методов и т.д. не называют так - "s". Почитайте конвенцию названий. Это отдельное искусство. На реальных проектах таких названий точно не будет)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ЗДЕСЬУВАСНИЧЕГОНЕТ</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

А самое главное, вам надо создать ваш jsp файл с названием, которое вы укажете из примера выше.

Например,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/helloworld</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

и создать файл helloworld.jsp, куда будет перенаправлен пользователь

Про папку WEB-INF не забудьте, как выше сказано